# Windows 10 paste timestamp anywhere

Tags: windows-10, user-input, windows-10-universal, user-experience

I´d like to have a shortcut to place a timestamp at any program that I use in Windows 10.
I didn't found any native resource for that.

I wonder if I could write some macro or script or some basic function that returns a timestamp, invoked by a shortcut, regardless of the current task that I´m working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went to my desktop, right click on it, and used the command : New >> shortcut.

After right click on this new shortcut, and selected 'Properties'.

In the 'General' tab I put "NOW CTRL + ALT + bar" in the first field (that´s the sortcut´s name).

In the 'Shortcut' tab I put the command above in the first field,
and "CTRL + Alt + /" in the third field.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with powershell.
Create a shortcut with this command line:

```
powershell.exe -c "Get-Date | Set-Clipboard"
```

Each time you start the shortcut, the clipboard will get a new timestamp.

Comment: Great! Is it possible to add the "paste" action somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format the date yourself... use the following:

Add a shortcut with

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -c "get-date -format 'dd/MMM/yy hh:mm' | Set-Clipboard"
```

= 04/Oct/23 10:03  - copied to clipboard

After right click on this new shortcut, and selected `Properties`.
In the `Shortcut` tab and put the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> in the field.

```
get-date -format "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm"   =   04-Oct-23 09:15
get-date -format "dd/MMM/yy hh:mm"  =   04/Oct/23 10:03
get-date -format "F" = 04 October 2023 18:02:44
```